# How to prove CYK algorithm has $O(n^3)$ running time

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, computational-complexity, automata, parsing

I have a final coming up in few days, and the professor mentioned the [CYK algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm). I want to be prepared for the final.

I'm trying to find out how to prove the algorithm has worst case running time of $n^3$.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but if you look at the pseudocode on the wikipedia article, then these are the only bits that iterate over $n$

```
for each i = 1 to n
    ....
for each i = 2 to n -- Length of span
  for each j = 1 to n-i+1 -- Start of span
    for each k = 1 to i-1 -- Partition of span
      ....
```

The first set of nested loops iterates to $n$ once $O(n)$ The second bit has lots of twiddly bits, but there are 3 loops to $n$ (or something that scales with it), so the second is order $O(n^3)$, and the whole thing is $O(n^3)$. You could do it more formally by saying that it

```
for each i = 2 to n -- Length of span
  for each j = 1 to n-i+1 -- Start of span
    for each k = 1 to i-1 -- Partition of span
      SOMETHING THAT TAKES TIME 1
```

then writting the running time as a sum
$$t = \sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} 1$$
which you can obtain an expression for
$$t = (n^3 - n)/6$$
so
$$ O(t) = O(n^3) $$